# Unable to stop page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using `events.peventDefault()` and `events.stopPropagation()`, unable to prevent page from reloading.

```
bindSearch: function() {

    var val = null;
    var input = null;
    config.bindThis('chatSearchFriends', 'body', 'searchBar', function(value, events) {

        input = $(value);               
        val = $(input).val();
        timer = setTimeout(doSearch, 1000);
        config.showThis('clearSearch');

        var keycode = (events.keyCode ? events.keyCode : events.which);

        if (keycode == '13' && !events.shiftKey) {
            //prevent page reload
            events.stopPropagation();
            events.preventDefault();

            console.debug('enter');
        }

    });

    config.bindThis('chatClearSearch', 'body', 'clearSearch', function(value, events) {

        //clear search text
    });

    function doSearch() {

      //fetch matched search
    }

},
```

In the code above, I bind **searchbox** on **keyup** event `(chatSearchFriends)`.

As user typing, if they pressed enter key the page should not reload, this is my concern.

The ajax will fetch matched data after 1 sec regardless the user press enter or not. That is done by this line: `timer = setTimeout(doSearch, 1000);`

So pressing enter should only stop page from reloading. I'm unsure why the above doesn't stop it.

bindThis:

```
bindThis: function(eventKey, bindTo, selectorKey, callback, bindOnceOnly = false) {

                        this.unBindThis(bindTo, eventKey);
                        if (bindOnceOnly) {

                            this.getSelectorDOM(bindTo).one(this.events[eventKey], this.selectors[selectorKey], function(e) {

                            callback(this, e);
                            });

                            return;
                        }

                        this.getSelectorDOM(bindTo).on(this.events[eventKey], this.selectors[selectorKey], function(e) {

                            callback(this, e);
                        });

                    },
```

Comment: In the first `event.preventDefault()` in the body, you spelled it `event.peventDefault()`.

Comment: In his code it is spelled correctly.

Comment: try to `unbind` before binding another function to the same object

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi, the hidden function (config.bindThis) does that.

Comment: Having no clue what `bindThis` is, does not help.

Comment: @epascarello, pls refer my edited post for that

Comment: Oh eyup is too late to block it.... that is AFTER the key is released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the code above, I bind searchbox on keyup event (chatSearchFriends).

You can not stop propagation of the key being press on key up. The event has already taken place. It has to be on keydown or keypress.